# Javascript code to open pop-up window on button click?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to know how to write a javascript code that will open a new 600*300 pop-up window on button click.

Let's say i have a open-up button in my Books.aspx ...and when i click "display", i want a few books to be display in the pop-up window, which is another web-form called BooksAuthor.aspx

**This is what i've tried so far:**

**Option 1**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" onClick="window.open('BooksAuthor.aspx');" Text="Display" /><br /><br />
```

**Option 2**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" onClick="openWindow();"Text="Display" /><br /><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
function openWindow()
{
    window.open("BooksAuthor.aspx", "status=1,width=600,height=300");
}
```

Nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What does the output HTML look like? Serverside technology is irrelevant for opening popups on the client.

Comment: you mean BooksAuthor.aspx ? it's empty so far. I just want to open the window for now and it can be empty @Halcyon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to call javascript on onClientClick

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('BooksAuthor.aspx');" Text="Display" /><br /><br />
```

Or

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="openWindow();" Text="Display" /><br /><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
function openWindow() {
    window.open("BooksAuthor.aspx", "status=1,width=600,height=300");
}
```

Comment: thanks, that works. although it doesn't seem to be the size i want. it is fully sized window

Answer (score 2):

To open custom sized window the proper syntax is

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

EX:-window.open("BooksAuthor.aspx", "MsgWindow", "width=600,height=300");